# Get id of fragment's view from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have a video view in fragment. When I press button it is showing as full view  in landscape mode but when I press back it should be come to normal view. For this I am handling `onBackPressed()` in Activity but I can't get the id of that video view in `Activity`. So how to get the video view id in `Activity`'s `onBackPressed()` which is there in `Fragment` class.

This is the code in `Fragment` to show video in full view:

```
fullScreen = (ImageView) controller.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
fullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 8.0f);
        videoView.setLayoutParams(param);
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    }
});
```

This is what I need to handle in the `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 5.0f);
    videoView.setLayoutParams(param);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

But I need `videoView` id here. How to get it in `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *brute force* way would be to get that view from your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    VideoView videoView = yourFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.your_video_view);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1. Call an interface method connecting your Fragment to the Activity.
2. Call a public method of the Fragment from your activity.

Comment: Methods 1 and 2 above require being able to invoke a method from one or the other object instances. Given that the Fragment object instance and Activity instance are independent object instances, how would one be able to invoke the other. Either would need the object variable of the other. How does this get shared between them?